# Pandas: Fill backwards missing values depending on another column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows:

```
      location col2
0       LA  NaN
1       LA    3
2       LA    5
3       LA  NaN
4       SF  NaN
5       SF  NaN
6       SF    7
7       SF    6
```

I am trying to fill missing values in "col2" backwards only if the location in the row above is equal to the location

for example only fill backwards when

```
df['location'] == df['location'].shift(-1)
```

is true.  So the final dataframe would like like:

```
  location col2
0       LA    3
1       LA    3
2       LA    5
3       LA  NaN
4       SF    7
5       SF    7
6       SF    7
7       SF    6
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `groupby()` + `bfill()`:

```
In [185]: df.groupby('location').col2.bfill()
Out[185]:
0    3.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
4    7.0
5    7.0
6    7.0
7    6.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

setting values back to `col2`:

```
In [186]: df.col2 = df.groupby('location').col2.bfill()

In [187]: df
Out[187]:
  location  col2
0       LA   3.0
1       LA   3.0
2       LA   5.0
3       LA   NaN
4       SF   7.0
5       SF   7.0
6       SF   7.0
7       SF   6.0
```

Comment: ^^^^^this!^^^^^